# plperl; The specified module could not be found Postgres 10 - Windows 10 - Strawberry Perl 5.24

Tags: plperl

When running the command:

```
CREATE LANGUAGE plperl;
```

I get an error:

> The specified module could not be found.

Running Windows 10 - Postgres 10 - Strawberry Perl 5.24

Comment: See [ask]. The idea is you ask a specific question about some code, show what you tried, and describe your results. Tooling questions are often on-topic, but you have to provide more details than this. Assume no one knows what any of this stuff you are referring to is. Show your research, and make sure you review what the internet has to offer, such as: http://www.mkyong.com/database/install-perl-in-postgresql-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found/

Comment: Good point, thanks.  I did try mkyoung.com, with no success. I loaded ActiveState Perl and have changed the postgres process to run under my local admin account. My local admin account has execute permissions on the Perl directories as well.  I'm able to execute a .pl fie from the command line.